# What is the value of r if the slope of the regression line is steeper than 1?

Tags: regression

What would be the value of r if the slope was steeper than in the leftmost diagram? Is r the slope or is it just proportional to the slope? Does it have anything to do with the quality of the regression (i.e., how much do the data points scatter around the regression line? - I think that is what r^2 is for, right?)

[image]

Comment: These diagrams presume both variables have been standardized to have unit variances.  In that case, the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality implies $r$ (the slope in standardized coordinates) must lie between $-1$ and $1.$ These plots also have to be understood as plotting the regression lines and not the data points.  The conditional variance of the points will be $1-r^2:$ although that quantity is not shown, you can compute it and visually estimate it.

Answer (score 2):

On its own, the slope tells you nothing about how good the fit is (unless the slope is exactly zero). If $\hat y_i =\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1x_i$:

$$
\hat\beta_1=r \dfrac{
s_y
}{
s_x
}
$$

In the above, $r$ is the observed correlation, $s_y$ is the observed (sample) standard deviation of $y$,and $s_x$ is the observed (sample) standard deviation of $x$.

Without knowing the ratio of standard deviations, the slope and correlation tell you nothing about one another besides the sign. (Assume you’re not in a silly situation where $y$ or $x$ are constant.)